# Get an array from nested objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

i have nested object users

```
let users = {
    '0LsRDanmw1s1KBvZAAAC': 
    { 
        name: 'user1',
        room: 'Lobby' 
    },
    'Qvd9v0EStnwNe11mAAAD': 
    { 
        name: 'user2',
        room: 'Music' 
    },

};
```

I want to get an array of users where `room === 'Lobby'`

```
let onlineUsers = ['user1'];
```

Thanks in advance

edit:
   alot of good solutions thank you guys!

Comment: Ok - so what's the question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get values, execute `.filter()` and then `.map()`.**

```js
let users = {    '0LsRDanmw1s1KBvZAAAC':     {         name: 'user1',        room: 'Lobby'     },    'Qvd9v0EStnwNe11mAAAD':     {         name: 'user2',        room: 'Music'     },};

var onlineUsers = Object.values(users)
                        .filter(u => u.room === 'Lobby')
                        .map(u => u.name);

console.log(onlineUsers );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Or you can get values and execute `.reduce()`.**

```js
let users = {    '0LsRDanmw1s1KBvZAAAC':     {         name: 'user1',        room: 'Lobby'     },    'Qvd9v0EStnwNe11mAAAD':     {         name: 'user2',        room: 'Music'     },};

var onlineUsers = Object.values(users)
                        .reduce((a, u) => (u.room === 'Lobby' ? [...a, u.name] : a), []);


console.log(onlineUsers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the values of the array, filter as desired and map only the name.

```js
var users = { '0LsRDanmw1s1KBvZAAAC': { name: 'user1', room: 'Lobby' }, 'Qvd9v0EStnwNe11mAAAD': { name: 'user2', room: 'Music' } },
    result = Object
        .values(users)
        .filter(({ room }) => room === 'Lobby')
        .map(({ name }) => name);
        
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Combination of `Object.values`, `filter` and `map`:

```js
let users = {'0LsRDanmw1s1KBvZAAAC': {   name: 'user1',room: 'Lobby' },'Qvd9v0EStnwNe11mAAAD':{ name: 'user2',room: 'Music' },};

const res = Object.values(users)
     .filter( o => o.room === 'Lobby')
     .map( o => o.name );
     
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **ES8** [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get all the values from the object, then apply `.filter` and `.map`

```js
let users = {
    '0LsRDanmw1s1KBvZAAAC': 
    { 
        name: 'user1',
        room: 'Lobby' 
    },
    'Qvd9v0EStnwNe11mAAAD': 
    { 
        name: 'user2',
        room: 'Music' 
    },

};

var onlineUsers = Object.values(users).filter(el => el.room==="Lobby").map(el => el.name);

console.log(onlineUsers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I still like the old school, old-browser-safe, version of a simple `for` loop, so for the sake of completeness:

```js
var users = {
    '0LsRDanmw1s1KBvZAAAC': 
    { 
        name: 'user1',
        room: 'Lobby' 
    },
    'Qvd9v0EStnwNe11mAAAD': 
    { 
        name: 'user2',
        room: 'Music' 
    },
};

var lobbyUsers = [];
for (var prop in users) {
    if (users.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        if (users[prop].room === 'Lobby') {
            lobbyUsers.push(users[prop].name);
        }
    }
}
console.log(lobbyUsers);
```